# android studio how to save which data was showed before closing?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

I am working on a learning app. I want to show the word which the user was learning before closing the app but whenever ı close and open the app it shows the first word.
I am using SQLite to store words.

Comment: You need to show some code. How are you iterating over words to learn? Have you tried using SharedPreferences to capture the latest word accessed?

Comment: thank you. I have tried shared, it took some time but it worked.